# PHP mail with AJAX won't return validation errors form server

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, validation, email

I am trying to send an email with PHP and AJAX, and it finally works, but it won't display validation errors returned from the server. I guess I'm doing something wrong in iterating through that data, or just don't understand something with connecting PHP and jQuery with JSON.

PHP mail script on server:

```
$to = "mymail@gmail.com";

if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['mail'], $_POST['text'])) {
    if (empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $errors[] = "Molimo unesite Vaše ime";
    } else {
        $contact_name = htmlentities($_POST['name']);
    }
if (empty($_POST['mail'])) {
    $errors[] = "Molimo unesite Vašu email adresu.";
} else if (strlen($_POST['mail']) > 60) {
    $errors[] = "Vaša email adresa je predugačka.";
} else if (filter_var($_POST['mail'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false ) {
    $errors[] = "Unesite validnu email adresu.";
} else {
    $contact_mail = "<" . htmlentities($_POST['mail']) . ">";
}

    if (empty($_POST['text'])) {
        $errors[] = "Molimo unesite poruku.";
    } else {
        $contact_text = htmlentities($_POST['text']);
    }
}

if (empty($errors) === true) {
    if(isset($contact_text, $contact_name, $contact_mail)) {
        $subject = "Mail from " . $contact_name ." via www.mysite.com";
        $headers = "From: " . $contact_mail;
        $sent = mail($to, $subject, $contact_text, $headers);
        if ($sent) {
            die("true");
        } else {
            return json_encode($errors);
        }
    }
}
```

Relevant jQuery:

```
var mailBroker = {
    send : function() { //initial validation and sending to server
        var contact_name = $('input[name="contact-name"]').val();
        var contact_mail = $('input[name="contact-mail"]').val();
        var contact_text = $('textarea[name="contact-text"]').val();
        var status = ""; //send success status

        if (contact_name === "" || contact_mail === "" || contact_text === "") {
            //form not complete
        } else {
            $.post("includes/mail.php", { //post form data to server
                name : contact_name,
                mail : contact_mail,
                text : contact_text
            }, function(data) {
                var response = data;
                if (data === "true") { //succesful
                    mailBroker.setStatus('Poruka poslata.');
                } else {
                    var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
                    $.each(parsedData, function() {
                        var that = $(this);
                        setStatus(that);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    },
    setStatus : function(status) {
        $('textarea[name="contact-text"]').after('<span>' + status + '</span>');
    }
}
```

And inside `$(document).ready()`:

```
$('#contact-us form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    mailBroker.send();
    $(this).trigger('reset');
});
```

Can somebody point out what I am doing wrong?

Of course, I know that I could just do it on the client-side, but that it is bad practice. So I left that part out for now and assumed that invalid or no data got through for required form fields.

Comment: Do you use a client-side tool to verify the response being sent back from the server? (firebug, for example)

Comment: Well, I didn't, but just because the mail got sent when I entered valid data. So - it works. Just the validation result on empty fields doesn't.

Comment: That's what I'm saying. Use firebug or something similar to make sure the server is actually sending what you are expecting when a field is empty or doesn't meet your validation. After that, then you can look in to your code - but make sure your JS function is receiving what you expect it to.

Comment: Also, you are only sending errors if the `mail` function didn't work. You need to `echo` the `json_encode`'d errors with an `else` after the `if (empty($errors) === true) {`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A little modification of Jon's answer because you will still need to extract the messages from the returned JSON:

```
var mailBroker = {
    'send' : function() { //initial validation and sending to server
        var contact_name = $('input[name="contact-name"]').val();
        var contact_mail = $('input[name="contact-mail"]').val();
        var contact_text = $('textarea[name="contact-text"]').val();
        var status = ""; //send success status

        $.post("includes/mail.php", { //post form data to server
            name : contact_name,
            mail : contact_mail,
            text : contact_text
        }, function(data) {
            var response = data;
            if (data === "true") { //succesful
                mailBroker.setStatus('Poruka poslata.');
                $('#contact-us form').trigger('reset');
            } else { //validation failed
                var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
                var msg = '';
                $.each(parsedData, function() {
                    var that = $(this);
                    for (var i = 0; i < that.size(); i++) {
                        msg += that[i];
                    }
                    mailBroker.setStatus(msg); //msg used to be 'that'
                    msg = '';
                });
            }
        });

    },

    'setStatus' : function(status) {
        $('#validation-msgs').prepend('<p class="validation-msg">' + status + '</p>');
    }
}
```

Essentially - you will need to pass through parsed data to get each of the messages. The problem is that they are also stored as arrays - of characters. So you will need to pass through those, too, and append those characters to a message String.

Then, you should prepend those messages to some container for warnings so they are in the right order. If you don't do that, you will get [Object] instead of the message text.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Answer form is easier to explain this. The logic in your code never gives your script a chance to output the errors to the AJAX. You'd need to change the logic so it will.  Ie.

```
if (empty($errors) === true) {
    if(isset($contact_text, $contact_name, $contact_mail)) {
        $subject = "Mail from " . $contact_name ." via www.mysite.com";
        $headers = "From: " . $contact_mail;
        $sent = mail($to, $subject, $contact_text, $headers);
        if ($sent) {
            die("true");
        } else {
            die("false"); // with json_encode here, $errors will always be empty
        }
    }
} else {
    die(json_encode($errors)); //$errors wasn't empty, this is where you need to hand it back to the JS.
}
```

This is why firebug or another tool would help. You'd see that the information you were wanting given to your JS wasn't there - that way you know to look at the PHP (server-side) since it isn't outputting as expected. If it was, you'd check in to the JS code to see why that isn't processing it as expected.

EDIT: Your javascript doesn't allow the PHP to execute when a field is empty, but you are wanting the feedback PHP will give if one is empty, so you'd want to change your JS to something like:

```
var mailBroker = {
    send : function() { //initial validation and sending to server
    var contact_name = $('input[name="contact-name"]').val();
    var contact_mail = $('input[name="contact-mail"]').val();
    var contact_text = $('textarea[name="contact-text"]').val();
    var status = ""; //send success status

    $.post("includes/mail.php", { //post form data to server
    name : contact_name,
    mail : contact_mail,
    text : contact_text
    }, function(data) {
    var response = data;
    if (data === "true") { //succesful
        mailBroker.setStatus('Poruka poslata.');
    } else {
        var parsedData = $.parseJSON(data);
        $.each(parsedData, function() {
        var that = $(this);
        setStatus(that);
        });
    }
    });
    },
    setStatus : function(status) {
    $('textarea[name="contact-text"]').after('<span>' + status + '</span>');
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to use firebug because I always relied on chrome. Furthermore, I am new to backend programming, so I'm not used to the tools yet.

I did look at the "Network" tab in chrome's Developer Tools. It seems that it doesn't send anything when there are fields missing. That is what it's supposed to do. But it doesn't give feedback.

One more thing, I looked up the die() function. It says that it is equivalent to exit() which returns nothing. I modified my code like you said, but tried with `return(json_encode($errors))`. Is that ok? Still not working, though :)

Comment: Die will echo out the what you put in it. `return` only works on functions. Use it like it's typed in the answer. Answers aren't any good if you change part of it away from its intent.

Comment: I tried your way first. I didn't question your methods. But it wouldn't work, so I googled the part that wasn't :)

Comment: A side note since you are new to PHP/backend.. `return` is used in methods/functions to give info back to php, to get it to Ajax response needs to be `echo` or output like you would for a normal page ^^

Comment: @NikolaMarkovic I just realized, in your JS, you cancel any operation if a field is empty. So it never sends it to the PHP. Try doing the post without checking in JS if any of them are empty (ie remove the `if (contact_name === "" || contact_mail === "" || contact_text === "") {` conditions for sending. That should post it to the PHP with empty fields, allowing your PHP to return the errors after the AJAX call. I updated my answer to show this. Try that JS, with the PHP above it and you should get the feedback without sending the mail.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I think you messed up on your line 3 mail script.
`if (isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['mail'], $_POST['text'])) {`
because you will use [comparison operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php) for that.

Like this below.

`if (isset($_POST['name'] && $_POST['mail'] && $_POST['text'])) {`

Comment: Or you can [Read the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) for [`isset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) and see that it is declared correctly how it is. Also, OP stated that mails were being sent successfully already, meaning passing that logic.

Comment: yeah you could do this `if (isset($_POST['name'] && $_POST['mail'] && $_POST['text'])) { echo $_POST['name'].'<br>'.$_POST['mail'].'<br>'.$_POST['text']; }` for debugging purposes.

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['name'], $_POST['mail'], $_POST['text']))` is the same as that. Click the links I posted above.

Comment: I can't echo it, because it is not on the page itself. It is a standalone php script on the server. I pass it the data, it sends the email. No validation info, though

Comment: @Nikola Markovic How do call the email script? via ajax? It will be helpful if you give us your form code.